# Route Param not working with React after deploying react application to apache server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created React app and using react-router in my application. I have used router param in Route. Whenever I try to access in local it is working fine, but when I deployed to apache server route params link is not working. Please help me.

My React Router Code :

```js
<BrowserRouter basename="tryloka_stg_app">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

        <Route exact path="/partner" component={Partner} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/signupOTP" component={SignUpOTP} />
        <Route exact path="/signupBirthday" component={SignupBirthday} />
         <Route exact path="/confirmPassword/:id" component={ConfirmPassword} />
  

        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Whenever i try to access http://35.181.69.171/tryloka_stg_app/confirmPassword/14 in production it shows a blank page with no error. But when I access in localhost like [localhost:3000/tryloka_stg_app/confirmPassword/14](http://35.181.69.171/tryloka_stg_app/confirmPassword/14) it is working fine.
**Build file location in server is** `/var/www/html/tryloka_stg_app`

My .htaccess file :

```js
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /tryloka_stg_app/index.html [QSA,L]
```

My package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "tryloka",
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.10.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "^18.4.48",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
   
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your homepage in package.json?

Comment: yes i have changed it to http://35.181.69.171/tryloka_stg_app/ but it is still showing blank page @ShyamKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy a react app to subdirectory

Add basename to route which you have already done

Make changes in the homepage  of package.json accordingly

"homepage": "http://35.181.69.171/tryloka_stg_app",

Comment: can you please mark the answer as correct?